# Square Line Picking

Tags: probability, geometry, reference-request, geometric-probability

The probability density function of the distance between two points chosen randomly on the unit square is [given by](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareLinePicking.html):

$
P(\ell) =
\begin{cases}
2\ell\left(\ell^2 - 4\ell + \pi\right) & 0 \leq \ell \leq 1 \\
2\ell\left[4\sqrt{\ell^2 - 1} - \left(\ell^2 + 2 - \pi\right)  - 4\arctan\sqrt{\ell^2 - 1} \right] & 1 \leq \ell \leq \sqrt{2}
\end{cases}
$

While this formula checks out empirically, unfortunately, only a personal communication is provided as reference for it.

I would be grateful if someone on here could help me understand how it was derived.

Answer (score 2):

I have the beginnings of what may be a solution:

Let $U = (U_1,U_2)$ and $W=(W_1,W_2)$ be two independent rv's with uniform distributions on the unit square, so $U_i,W_i \sim f(x) := I_{[0,1]}(x)$. Let 
$D := ((U_1-W_1)^2 + (U_2-W_2)^2)^{1/2}$ be the distance between the two random points. 
First suppose $d \in [1,\sqrt{2}]$. Write 
\begin{align}
   P[D \leq d \mid W]
&= \int_{(u_1,u_2) \in B_d(W_1,W_2)} du_1 du_2 \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{W_1 + \sqrt{d^2 - (u_2-W_2)^2}} du_1 du_2 \\
&= \int_0^1 (W_1 + \sqrt{d^2 - (u_2-W_2)^2}) du_2 \\
&= W_1 + \int_0^1 \sqrt{d^2 - (u_2-W_2)^2}) du_2.
\end{align}
For the last integral on the right, Wolfram alpha gives the anti-derivative
$$
  \frac{1}{2}\left((u_2-W_2)\sqrt{d^2-(W_2-u_2)^2}+d^2
  \arctan\left(\frac{u_2-W_2}{\sqrt{d^2-(W_2-u_2)^2}}\right)\right),
$$
and so if $g_1(w) = \sqrt{d^2 - (w-1)^2}$ and $g_0(w) = \sqrt{d^2 - w^2}$ one finds
$$
  P[D \leq d \mid W]
= W_1 + \frac{1}{2}\left( (1-W_2)g_1(W_2)+d^2 
  \arctan\left(\frac{1-W_2}{g_1(W_2)}\right)\right) -\frac{1}{2}\left( -W_2g_0(W_2)+d^2
  \arctan\left(\frac{-W_2}{g_0(W_2)}\right) \right).
$$
Then the distribution function for $D$ is 
\begin{align}
   P[D \leq d]
&= {\bf E}[P[D \leq d \mid W]].
\end{align}
Now, 
\begin{align}
   {\bf E}\left[  (1-W_2)g_1(W_2) + W_2 g_0(W_2) \right]
&= \int_0^1 ((1-w)\sqrt{d^2-(1-w)^2} + w\sqrt{d^2-w^2} )dw \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 w\sqrt{d^2-w^2} dw \\
&= \left. -\frac{2}{3}(d^2-w^2)^{3/2} \right|^1_0 \\
&= \frac{2}{3}(d^3 - (d^2 - 1)^{3/2}), 
\end{align}
and, since 
\begin{align}
   {\bf E}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{1-W_2}{g_1(W_2)}\right) \right]
&= \int_0^1 \arctan\left(\frac{1-w}{\sqrt{d^2-(1-w)^2}}\right) dw \\
&= \int_0^1 \arctan\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{d^2-y^2}}\right) dy \\
&= {\bf E}\left[-\arctan\left(\frac{-W_2}{g_0(W_2)}\right) \right],
\end{align}
one has
\begin{align}
   {\bf E}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{1-W_2}{g_1(W_2)}\right) - 
   \arctan\left(\frac{-W_2}{g_0(W_2)}\right) \right]
&= 2\int_0^1 \arctan\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{d^2-y^2}}\right) dy \\
&= \left. 2\left(\sqrt{d^2 - w^2} + w\arctan\left(\frac{w}{\sqrt{d^2-w^2}}\right) \right) 
   \right|^1_0 \\
&= 2\left(\sqrt{d^2 - 1} + \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{d^2-1}}\right) - d \right).
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
   P[D \leq d]
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}(d^3 - (d^2 - 1)^{3/2}) + 
   d^2\left(\sqrt{d^2 - 1} + \arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{d^2-1}}\right) - d \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{-2d^3 - (d^2 - 1)^{3/2}+3d^2\sqrt{d^2-1}}{3}  +
   d^2 \arctan\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{d^2-1}}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{-2d^3 +(2d^2 +1)\sqrt{d^2-1}}{3}  
   +d^2 \arctan\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{d^2-1}}\right).
\end{align}
Differentiating with respect to $d$ should yield the density for $D$:
\begin{align}
   f_D(d)
&= -2d^2 + \frac{d(2d^2-1)}{\sqrt{d^2-1}}+2d\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{d^2-1}} \right) -
   \frac{d}{\sqrt{d^2-1}} \\
&= -2d^2 + \frac{2d(d^2-1)}{\sqrt{d^2-1}}+2d\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{d^2-1}} \right) \\
&= 2d\left( -d + \sqrt{d^2-1}+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{d^2-1}} \right)\right),
\end{align}
$1\leq d \leq \sqrt{2}$. Now use the identity $\arctan(1/x) = -\frac{1}{2}\pi - \arctan(x)$ to get

\begin{align}
   f_D(d)
&= 2d\left(\sqrt{d^2-1} -d  -\frac{1}{2}\pi-\arctan(\sqrt{d^2-1}) \right), \quad 
   1 \leq d \leq \sqrt{2}.
\end{align}
As you can see, this gives a slightly different density in the region $[1,\sqrt{2}]$, but there may be some other trig identity that makes them equal (I really doubt it). Is this helpful? Sorry I couldn't get to the density you have.